# How to align button text

Tags: qt, qml

I have a button with some text which is normally centered, but I want this text to align to the left. I have tried some things but they don't seem to work. Is this possible, if yes how can it be done?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400

    Button {
        id: button
        text: "Align me to the left"
        //horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        width: parent.width
        height: 30
        flat: true
        onClicked: {
            console.log("You clicked me")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always [customize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button) it to look however you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [customize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button) a Button, you can override the `contentItem` and/or `background` properties. If you want left-aligned text, just use the `contentItem` to create a Text object that looks the way you want it.

```
Button {
    contentItem: Text {
        text: parent.text
        font: parent.font
        horizontalAlignment : Text.AlignLeft
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You an use 'parent' instead of the id of the button to be more generic:
`text: parent.text
font: parent.font`

Comment: Yes, that simplifies it a little. But there are times when using `parent` is safe, and times when it is not. You are making an assumption that `contentItem` is a direct child of the Button, but that's an implementation detail that is not guaranteed to always be true.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button {
    id: button
    contentItem: Text {
        text: "Align me to the left"
        horizontalAlignment : Text.AlignLeft
    }
    width: parent.width
    height: 30
    flat: true
    onClicked: {
        console.log("You clicked me")
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this puts a new text element on top of the existing one. If you set the button's built-in `text` property, you'll see overlapping text.

Comment: Good point, and well worth mentioning, but...I don't believe that alignment properties for the text element are exposed to the programmer, so I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: I already provided a link in my comment above that shows how to customize a button.

Comment: Yes you did...I edited my response accordingly. Next time, I'll read more carefully.